# PHP POST data to another page using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I currently have a form in PHP that gets validated using JQuery and the data is submitted to the DB. During the `INSERT` I'm getting the `ID` of the user that was inserted.
On success, it redirects the user to the next page which I then want to display the `$user_id`. I know I should be using `get` or some other method but unsure how to go about it with my current set up. Any help would be appreciated.

JS

```
                var submitRequest = $.ajax({
                     type: "POST",
                     url: "submit.php",
                     data: user_data
                });

                submitRequest.done(function(msg)
                {
                    //success
                   // / console.log('success');
                   window.location.href = "nextpage.php";
                });
```

PHP

```
$query_user ="INSERT INTO mytable(name,email) VALUES ('".$name."', '".$email."' )";
$sql_user =mysql_query($query_user) or die (mysql_error());
$user_id = mysql_insert_id();
```

nextpage.php

```
//How can I get it to display $user_id?
```

Comment: [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below :-

PHP

```
$query_user ="INSERT INTO mytable(name,email) VALUES ('".$name."', '".$email."' )";
$sql_user =mysql_query($query_user) or die (mysql_error());
$user_id = mysql_insert_id();
echo $user_id;
```

JS

```
submitRequest.done(function(msg)
                {
                    //success
                   // / console.log('success');
                   window.location.href = "nextpage.php?id="+msg; // msg will consist userid
                });
```

nextpage.php

```
$userid = $_GET["id"];
```